# WP8 Mail Pivot App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

I wish to copy the same mechanics of the Mail app in Windows Phone 8.

When you fire the Mail app, it allows you to select an email which will, in a cool animated fashion, open up the email showing it's Subject, Body etc etc.

How can I achieve this in the default Pivot app?

Pivot XAML code:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="Read the Signs" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <phone:PivotItem Header="abc" Foreground="Black">
        <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
        <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </phone:PivotItem>
       ......
       ......
       ......
</phone:Pivot>
```

In this application, the `TextBlock` which has a text binding of `Location` is the item which I want to be clickable and for a new Window to open. Just like the Mail app...

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish a simple slide up transition you can the approach in [this blog](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2013/12/15/Creating-simple-page-transitions-using-Storyboards-Slide-transition.aspx). It creates simple extension methods that allow you to slide the content of the page up when it is navigated to.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    try
    {
        await LayoutRoot.TransitionInSlideUp();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of purchasing http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/databoundlistbox.aspx. Will that have the cool navigation AND a pull to refresh control? as I need that as well.

Comment: It does. But I would look into the [Nokia program](http://developer.nokia.com/Developer_Programs/nokia_developer_offers.xhtml), which offers telerik, and more.